# JFreeChart axes appear different depending on execution environment

Tags: tomcat, jfreechart, axis-labels

This is a little strange.  I have code that generates a chart in JFreeChart and saves it as a .svg file.  If I run the code via a test method in Eclipse, it outputs as follows:

[image: Graph from Test Method]

Note the nice LogAxis labels.

Now if I execute the exact same code in a controller in Tomcat, I the following image:

[image: Graph as created from Tomcat]

Note that while the arcs are identical, the axes on the second image are no longer showing the nice logarithmic progression.  This wouldn't bother me, except that in the second case the tick marks are not only not showing the nice logarithm, they're wrong.

Following is the controller code that generates the graph.  Note that some things are hardwired in a way that wouldn't be normally - this is because this is a rapid prototype

```
    private static final String pn = "T495D477M004ATE100";

       private File generateMaxCurrentVoltageGraph()
             throws IOException, InitializationException, ClassNotFoundException
       {
          String title = "Current and Voltage - " + pn + " @ 25\u00B0C with 2 VDC Bias";
          String frequencyAxisLabel = "Frequency (Hz)";
          String valueAxisLabel1 = "Max Current (ARMS)";
          String valueAxisLabel2 = "Max Voltage (VRMS)";

          List datasets = createVoltageCurrentDatasets();
          JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(title, frequencyAxisLabel, valueAxisLabel1, null, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, false, false);
          chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

          final XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
          plot.setDataset(0, datasets.get(0));
          plot.setDataset(1, datasets.get(1));

          plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
          plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.lightGray);
          plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.lightGray);

          final XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer1 = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
          renderer1.setSeriesShapesVisible(0, false);
          renderer1.setSeriesShapesVisible(1, false);
          renderer1.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.red);
          plot.setRenderer(0, renderer1);
          final XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer2 = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
          renderer2.setSeriesShapesVisible(0, false);
          renderer2.setSeriesShapesVisible(1, false);
          renderer2.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.blue);
          plot.setRenderer(1, renderer2);

          final LogAxis rangeAxis1 = new LogAxis(valueAxisLabel1);
          rangeAxis1.setStandardTickUnits(LogAxis.createLogTickUnits(Locale.ENGLISH));
          rangeAxis1.setRange(0.1, 10.0); //100 mA to 10 A
          rangeAxis1.setNumberFormatOverride(new UnitNumberFormat(UnitValue.AMPS));
          rangeAxis1.setLabelPaint(Color.red);
          plot.setRangeAxis(0, rangeAxis1);

          final LogAxis rangeAxis2 = new LogAxis(valueAxisLabel2);
          rangeAxis2.setStandardTickUnits(LogAxis.createLogTickUnits(Locale.ENGLISH));
          rangeAxis2.setRange(0.01, 10.0); //10 mV to 10 V
          rangeAxis2.setNumberFormatOverride(new UnitNumberFormat(UnitValue.VOLTS));
          rangeAxis2.setLabelPaint(Color.blue);
          plot.setRangeAxis(1, rangeAxis2);
          plot.mapDatasetToRangeAxis(1, 1);

          final LogAxis domainAxis = new LogAxis(frequencyAxisLabel);
          domainAxis.setStandardTickUnits(LogAxis.createLogTickUnits(Locale.ENGLISH));
          domainAxis.setRange(100, 10000000); //100Hz to 10MHz
          domainAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(new UnitNumberFormat(UnitValue.HERTZ));
          plot.setDomainAxis(domainAxis);

          LegendTitle legendTitle = chart.getLegend();
          LegendTitle legendTitleNew = new LegendTitle(plot, new ColumnArrangement(), new ColumnArrangement());
          legendTitleNew.setPosition(legendTitle.getPosition());
          legendTitleNew.setBackgroundPaint(legendTitle.getBackgroundPaint());
          legendTitleNew.setBorder(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25);
          chart.removeLegend();
          chart.addLegend(legendTitleNew);

          chart.getTitle().setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
          chart.getTitle().setFont(rangeAxis1.getLabelFont());
          chart.getTitle().setExpandToFitSpace(true);
          chart.setPadding(new RectangleInsets(10, 10, 10, 10));

          File graphFile = File.createTempFile("CurrentVoltageGraph", ".svg");

          return writeGraphFile(chart, graphFile);
       }


       private List createVoltageCurrentDatasets()
             throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InitializationException, ClassNotFoundException
       {
          List datasets = new ArrayList();
          XYSeriesCollection dataset1 = new XYSeriesCollection();
          XYSeriesCollection dataset2 = new XYSeriesCollection();
    //      String sourceDataPath = "/etc/intellidata/prototype/CurrentVoltageTestGraphData.csv";
          String sourceDataPath = "C:\\Users\\BrianTrezise\\Desktop\\Downloads\\CurrentVoltageTestGraphData.csv";
          CSVRowIterator csv = new CSVRowIterator(new FileInputStream(sourceDataPath));
          XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("T495D477M004ATE100-I");
          XYSeries series2 = new XYSeries("T495D477M004ATE100-V");

          while(csv.hasNext())
          {
             Row row = csv.next();
             String frequencyString = (String) row.get("Frequency");
             String currentString = (String) row.get("Current");
             String voltageString = (String) row.get("Voltage");

             Double frequency = decodeValue(frequencyString);
             Double current = decodeValue(currentString);
             Double voltage = decodeValue(voltageString);

             series1.add(frequency, current);
             series2.add(frequency, voltage);
          }

          dataset1.addSeries(series1);
          datasets.add(dataset1);
          dataset2.addSeries(series2);
          datasets.add(dataset2);

          return datasets;
       }


       private File writeGraphFile(JFreeChart chart, File graphFile)
             throws IOException
       {
          // Get a DOMImplementation and create an XML document
          DOMImplementation domImpl = GenericDOMImplementation.getDOMImplementation();
          Document document = domImpl.createDocument(null, "svg", null);

          // Create an instance of the SVG Generator
          SVGGraphics2D svgGenerator = new SVGGraphics2D(document);
          svgGenerator.setSVGCanvasSize(new Dimension(720, 470));

          // draw the chart in the SVG generator
          Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(10, 10, 700, 450);
          chart.draw(svgGenerator, bounds);

          // Write svg file
          OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(graphFile);
          Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
          svgGenerator.stream(out, true /* use css */);
          outputStream.flush();
          outputStream.close();

          return graphFile;
       }
```

Does anybody have any ideas as to why it would behave differently in Tomcat than it would when executed directly from Eclipse?
Note: I'm also generating a second graph that does the same thing.  Works fine from the test method, same code executed withing a Tomcat controller has the weird, incorrect tick marks in between the logarithmic ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I still don't know why the behavior is different in tomcat than it is in Eclipse.  That said, inserting the following line of code (for each data axis) seems to resolve the problem:

rangeAxis1.setAutoTickUnitSelection(false);

If anybody can add additional information on this however I'd be appreciative

Comment: I can't comment on environment differences, but using your line of code above avoided JFreeChart creating seemingly random-spaced minor tick label intervals. Thanks so much!